# SDL Tridion User sessions getting mixed (conflicted)

Tags: 2011

In one of our Tridion setup we are getting problem regarding user session conflicting, as mentioned in following use case :-

1.Content Editor A connects to Tridion CME with his credentials.

2.Content Editor B or Administrator connects to Tridion CME with his credentials on another machine.

3.Content Editor B edits a component or page in Tridion and publishes the item.

4.Suddenly when Content editor A refreshes browser session, user gets session of content editor B (like... "welcome user B").

5. Even Editor A edited an item and the history shows the item last edited by user B.

Please let me know if anyone faced this issue and found any solution may be if something incorrect in our implementation.

We are using IIS 7.0 to host the Tridion website and to authenticate users we are using Windows authentication.
The SDL Tridion website is hosted on 4 servers and a Apache Proxy over that, also as found in some recommendations we have disabled Output Cache on IIS servers(as it seems IIS output cache may be a suspected cause).

Comment: Sounds like your IIS could be mis-configured. Can you check the authentication settings for the SDL Tridion website? Are you using an SSO system?

Comment: How is authentication done? LDAP? AD? SSO?

Comment: Hi Nuno and David, I have checked the authentication mode its SSO.

Comment: You did not mention the Apache proxy before. Is that doing any caching? Are you using this for load balancing?

Comment: @David, my apology for missing information. Yes the Proxy is used for load balancing. I tried to disable cache for apache server using following script:-                                                                           <filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>

Comment: @DavidForster, I have update my question to answer your queries. Please let me know if anything I am doing is incorrect.

Comment: Well, the first thing that occurs to me is, does that filesMatch statement only match .htm, .html, .js and .css files? Because if so, I don't think that's sufficient for Tridion. I think you need to determine whether the Apache proxy is really the problem by having multiple users access a Tridion server directly at the same time.

Comment: @DavidForster, Ok I'll work on your suggestion and update you accordingly.

Comment: @DavidForster, i checked directly on servers with multiple users logged, its not recreating the problem.

Comment: @user2166 Great. Then I think you need to check your Apache configuration thoroughly. Sounds like it's caching too much and/or not handling authentication correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52449/discussion-between-user2166-and-david-forster).

Comment: @DavidForster, thanks for your suggestions, when we bypassed the proxy, seems we are not getting the issue related to user session conflicting. Seems something was incorrect with proxy. Once again thanks for your support.